# Use fig and docker-machine to deploy remotely

Tags: docker, fig

I use docker-machine to easily create docker hosts on AWS.

Locally I use fig (or docker-compose) to start the various microservices associated with a service.

Is it possible for fig to use the config variables set by the docker-machine command:

```
 docker-machine config host
```

So when I do:

```
fig up
```

Fig creates the service on the host set by docker-machine and not the local one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tried to do this with a remote host but I have it working with a `vmwarefusion` based machine. Because [fig respects some of the `DOCKER_` environment variables](http://www.fig.sh/cli.html) you can modify them to point to your docker host. Try something like this:

```
$(docker-machine env host); docker-compose up
```

Edited previous approach (referenced in comments):

```
#!/bin/bash

# modify path and host with output from > docker-machine config host
DOCKER_CERT_PATH=~/.docker/machines/.client/
DOCKER_HOST=tcp://172.16.124.216:2376
DOCKER_TLS_VERIFY=1

fig up
```

Comment: Perfect. to make it easier to fill the env variables I just have to do:
    $(docker-machine env hostA)

Comment: Oh good, I had tried using the sub-shell command and had a problem with that so didn't include it in my answer. I'll try that again and update the answer in the future. I'll also probably change the answer to use `docker-compose`.